# Remove .com, .net etc. from URL string

Tags: php

If $domain = apple.com, or mit.org.edu.au, how can I remove the '.com' and everything starting from the dot using PHP? e.g. apple.com becomes apple, mit.org.edu.au becomes mit (disregard www.).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), please.

Comment: can this happen?? @JohnConde

Comment: @PranavKapoor Not quite, OP is asking for the first token, dup is asking for everything but the last.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you already have the domain then simply explode the domain and take the first element of the array.

```
$domain = 'apple.com';
$domain_parts = explode('.', $domain);
echo $domain_parts[0]; // returns apple
```

Note that the above will not account for subdomains.  I.e. 'www.apple.com' would return 'www'.  But based on what you have asked above, explode may be adequate.

If you don't already have the domain then you can use PHP's [parse_url function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the domain (host) from the URL.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$domain1 = 'apple.com';
$domain2 = 'mit.org.edu.au';
$exploded1 = explode('.',$domain1);
$exploded2 = explode('.',$domain2);
echo $exploded1[0];
echo $exploded2[0];
?>
```

See PHP's [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. Here's a **[codepad](http://codepad.org/SjOq6Io3)** example.

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$tokens = explode(".", "apple.com");
echo $tokens[0]; // apple
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple one line answer:

```
<?php echo explode('.', $url)[0]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, use explode.
    $raw = 'apple.com';
    $url = explode('.',$raw);
    echo $url[0];

If there is a "www" in the domain, then do a simple check like
    if($url[0] == 'www'){
    echo $url[1];
    }else{
    echo $url[0];
    }

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to make it appear in the code box, I am new to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike all of these answers... if you KNOW the domain, none of this is necessary... if you DONT KNOW the domain, you most certainly should account for subdomains.

```
$parts = explode('.', $domain);

array_pop($parts); //remove the TLD

$url = join('.', $parts);  //put it back together, sans the TLD
```